# i can't install any package in my angular project

Tags: angular

i would like to install popperjs in my angular project :
i used this commande :  `npm install @popperjs/core --save`.
It's giving me as an error :

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@12.1.2
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.0.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/cdk@14.0.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@"14.0.4" from @angular/material@14.0.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!       @angular/material@"^14.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^14.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"14.0.5" from @angular/forms@14.0.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!     peer @angular/forms@"^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/material@14.0.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!       @angular/material@"^14.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     @angular/forms@"^14.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR!   5 more (@angular/material, @angular/platform-browser, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^13.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@12.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!   @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^12.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@13.3.11
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^13.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@12.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^12.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

i don't understand the problem exactly,

Ps : i tried `npm install @popperjs/core --legacy-peer-deps` but it's showing me others errors :

```
added 1 package, and audited 1246 packages in 14s

123 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

31 vulnerabilities (7 moderate, 15 high, 9 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```

this probeleme i got it with any package that i want to install.
i tried to create a new angular project and the installation is working fine but in my actual project it's giving me those errors.

Whene i created my project the first time i created with the V13 of angulat;after that i upgrade the version with this commande:  `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`
now my vesrion of angular is 14

```
ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___ 
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | | 
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | | 
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 14.0.5
Node: 16.15.0
Package Manager: npm 8.10.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 14.0.5
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1400.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.0.5
@angular-devkit/core            14.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.0.5
@angular/cdk                    14.0.4
@schematics/angular             14.0.5
rxjs                            7.5.5
typescript                      4.6.4
```

Comment: Can you add more details like your package.json file, what's the node/npm version your are running?

Comment: @Nehal , i added more details in my question

Answer (score 2):

Your error log tells you the conflicting dependency issue here:

```
Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^13.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@12.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!   @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^12.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@13.3.11
```

ng-bootstap [dependency doc](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap#dependencies) has clearly listed compatible angular versions. Either upgrade `ng-bootstap` to v13 to make it work with Angular 14, or downgrade Angular to v13 to use ng-bootstap v12.x

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer : but  sorry i don't undrestand  ; before i ugrade angular version , i had the version 13 , and in the doc they mention that   g-bootstrap@ v-12.1.2 is compatible  with  angular v-13 , but in my case  i had always this error

Comment: It means in your package.json file all `@angular/*` dependencies need to be `13.x.x` to use `@ng-boostrap` v12.x. If you want to keep `@angular/*` to `14.x.x`, then in your package.json, list `"@ng-boostrap": "13.0.0-beta.1"`

Comment: @work you what you have is Angular v14 and not 13 so that's why you having the issue.